# How to deal with nparrays faster

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

I have two images loaded in to two numpy array. I want to get the difference of them and remove the values less than 50 and set the rest of it to 255 with a final result of back and white image.

```
def count(base, image):
    x, y, z = base.shape
    sheet = np.zeros(base.shape)
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            temp = 0
            for k in range(z):
                if base[i, j, k] > image[i, j, k]:
                    t = base[i, j, k] - image[i, j, k]
                    if t > 50:
                        temp = 255
                else:
                    t = image[i, j, k] - base[i, j, k]
                    if t > 50:
                        temp = 255
            sheet[i, j] = [temp, temp, temp]

    array = sheet[:, :, 0]
```

this code does what i need it to do. but as you see i have used the most simplest for loop for this function and with the images being in the size of 2000*2000, it takes a long time to process. i need a way to rewrite this in a faster way.

thank you

Comment: `sheet = np.array([[0,0,0],[255,255,255]], 'u1')[(np.abs(image-base)>50).any(2).view('u1')]`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer this doesn't give the same results as the code.. seems like most of the pixels are 255 in this case.. having hard time figuring out how to edit.

Comment: Argh, those bleedin' unsigned types! How's that: `sheet = np.array([[0,0,0],[255,255,255]], 'u1')[((np.maximum(base, image)-np.minimum(base, image))>50).any(2).view('u1')]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vectorizing your code looks straight-forward, except for one gotcha: Your data appear  to be unsigned ints (`uint8` by the look of it) which require a bit of extra attention since they frequently underflow with unexpected results. For example, the obvious `np.abs(image-base)>50` to detect differences greater than 50 does not work, in fact `np.abs` is a nop on unsigned data. A careful translation would look more like

```
sheet = np.array([[0,0,0],[255,255,255]], 'u1')[((np.maximum(base, image)-np.minimum(base, image))>50).any(2).view('u1')]
```

or

```
sheet = np.array([[0,0,0],[255,255,255]], 'u1')[(np.abs(np.subtract(image, base, dtype='i2'))>50).any(2).view('u1')]
```

This

1. correctly computes the subpixel wise difference,

   - the first version mimics your if/else clause
   - the second forces a signed result type `'i2'` or `int16` for the difference
2. detects those greater 50,
3. marks pixels with at least one such subpixel (`any(2)`),
4. converts the resulting boolean mask into indices (`.view('u1')`) 0 and 1
5. and uses those to index into a template array.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the operations work just as they would on scalars on NumPy arrays of the same size. I re-wrote the function as,

```
def count_new(base, image, thresh=50):
    # these are the pixel absolute value differences
    differences = np.abs(base - image)

    # whether the difference exceeds the threshold
    big_difference = differences > thresh

    # whether each pixel has at least one big difference
    big_difference = big_difference.any(axis=2)

    # return 255 where big differences, and 0 everywhere else
    return 255 * big_difference.astype(int)
```

Hopefully the comments make the intent of each line clear. Also checked this gives the same as the previous out-put

```
x = np.random.randint(256, size=(10, 11, 3))
y = np.random.randint(256, size=(10, 11, 3))
assert((count(x,y) == count_new(x,y)).all())
```

which shows it does.